# Fetch the smallest date of an object in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, fetching-strategy

I'm having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806643/core-data-trying-to-find-minimum-date-for-an-attribute-in-an-entity), but the answer of @davedelong is not working for me.

When following the [Apple Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6), for fetching the smallest date in a set of object I get the following error

```
-[NSDate count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

My understanding is that `NSExpression`'s max: only support `NSArray`s. So I need an other solution.

@davedelong suggested using an ascending `NSSortDescriptor`, and so I did :

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([GCSession class])
                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

NSSortDescriptor* sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];

GCSession* session = [[self.objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] lastObject];

return session.startDate;
```

The problem here is that the `session` object returned from the fetch doesn't seems to be the one with the smallest `startDate`. In my tests, it seems that it even returned the *newest* date but it doesn't seems consistent.

I could also fetch every `GCSession` object and sort them but that seems way overkill, especially that `GCSession` will be augmenting in number when the users will use the application.

*Edit* : [A test project](http://cl.ly/3S3l0N2s471r0j1m2A1o) that demonstrate the bug in Apple's example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sort only comes into play after you've fetch the objects. You've set a fetch limit of one and no predicates which tells the fetch "go grab any random single GCSession object". One the fetch has an array 1 element long, it then sorts it, which is useless.

If you want to use a sort to find a min or max, you have to fetch all the objects and then sort them. Removing the line:

```
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
```

… should allow the code to work.

However, you should be able to fetch min and max values with expressions. It's kind of a basic operation.

Edit: Look at the comments for more detail, but Apple's example can work if you change the backing store to SQL instead of XML

Comment: That's what I thought also about `fetchLimit`, but I was referring to the answer of the previous question. When you say that I should be able to fetch max and min, how can I do that? (considering that the Apple's example is crashing on me)

Comment: The Apple example code works fine for me running on Xcode 4.1 and building for iPhone simulator 4.3. You've probably got something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Well, it seems that the example is iOS only even if it's in the Mac OS X dev centre… Updated my answer with a test project.

Comment: I can confirm that the test project fails although at this point I don't know why. You might want to open a question specifically to address that. I'll poke around and see what might be causing it. It might be related to the XML store the test code is using instead of the sqlite store I used to test the Apple example.

Comment: It is a problem with the XML store. Changing the store type to sqlite fixes the problem. To  my knowledge however, the min expression should work with an XML store.

Comment: Wow that did work. Thanks a lot. I honestly don't think I would have thought that myself.

Comment: Thanks, wish I knew why it broke with XML though.